# My query doesn't appear to be adding to the database/returning results

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am trying to insert into a database with SQLlite.

I have the following code:

```
function storeUserStatus(s) {
    console.log("STATUS");

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO calculator (leadership, status, wealth, social, random, control) VALUES  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5]], function(success) {
            console.log(success);
        }),
                function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                };
    });
}
```

s is an array with only numeric values (both negative and positive), and the success callback is the callback getting executed.

Why is it not inserting? I try to do a query later on, and the query isn't finding any results.

The query I'm using to get the data (which is returning nothing) is this:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
tx.executeSql('SELECT id FROM calculator ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1' ...
```

Why would I not be getting any resultset?

My table creation is like this:

```
function populateDB(tx) {
    //Create the table
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS calculator (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY \
                            leadership UNSIGNED INTEGER, status UNSIGNED INTEGER, wealth UNSIGNED INTEGER, \
                            social UNSIGNED INTEGER, random UNSIGNED INTEGER, control UNSIGNED INTEGER) \
                             '
                );
}
```

When I look at the results for the select:

```
console.log(results.rows.item);
```

Now I'm getting this:

```
 function item() { [native code] }
```

but

`console.log(results.rows.item[0]);` is undefined, and it says, rowsAffected: 0

Comment: did you forget to use `db.transation` with the sql select command?

Comment: No, I just didn't include it with the example. I'll add it to my example.